# How to fetch User role in specific Subscription based on the user mail id

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, postman, office365api, azure-rest-api

How to check the users role(owner, reader) in that specific azure subscription by using user mail id has parameter in azure rest apis?

is there any api to get the data has mentioned above?
(or)
is there any api to fetch total users list with user roles in that specific subscription ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two APIs available to fetch user roles

- **[Azure Active Directory Graph API (old)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api)**
- [**Microsoft Graph graph.microsoft.com (new).**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)